# Content crossing in many instances of laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Sorry for my english.
I have many instances of laravel in a remote webserver

1. htdocs/laravel1/public
2. htdocs/laravel2/public
3. htdocs/laravel3/public

The problem is when I access to any laravel app, this show me the static content of that laravel app but the dinamic content of any other 2.

If I access via browser to laravel1/public this should show me  the website of laravel1, but really show me only the static content of that laravel app, but the dynamic content like a menu elements and DB content is of laravel2 or laravel3 app.

How can I do for separate the projects?, I don't want the projects cross between each other

Comment: so what is the question here?

Comment: You should be more specific. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is when I access to any laravel app, this show me the static content of that laravel app but the dinamic content of any other 2.

If I access via browser to laravel1/public this should show me the website of laravel1, but really show me only the static content of that laravel app, but the dynamic content like a menu elements and DB content is of laravel2 or laravel3 app.

How can I do for separate the projects?, I don't want the projects cross between each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem solved.
Everything is given to XCache in php, although laravel is not using XCache with caching, XCache if it does.

I try increasing the size in flag xcache.var.size to 100 but it does not work.

The solution ?: disable the XCache module in (global)master by php.ini or xcache.ini, or local by a .htaccess.